# Sqlite with EFCore version 7.0.0 does not load database for in-memory connections. Fails with 'SQLite Error 1: ''.' at EnsureDeleted()

Tags: .net, sqlite, .net-6.0, ef-core-7.0

For Unit Testing, I am using EFCore SQLite in-memory db and creating schema as per the MS docs, but when the code attempts to execute EnsureDeleted(). It fails at with exception 'SQLite Error 1: ''.'

Not much details are provided in the exception and it fails provided below stacktrace.

First part of stacktrace:
[image]

second part of stacktrace:
[image]

The code uses Dotnet with version .net6.0 and for EFcore and Sqlite below are the packages with versions

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="7.0.0" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.0" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="7.0.0" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite" Version="7.0.0" />`

The code I use to make the connection is as below

```
var dbConnection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
dbConnection.Open();
var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDBContext>()
    .UseSqlite(dbConnection, opt => opt.UseNetTopologySuite())
    .Options;

TestDBContext db = new TestDBContext(dbOptions);
db.Database.EnsureDeleted(); // This is where it fails.
db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

1. I have tried changing the connection string from "Filename=:memory:" to different variations.
2. Tried adding or removing different packages.

Nothing has helped so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite v7.0.0`.
You can try updating your code to

```
.UseSqlite(dbConnection)
```

and it should run with no problem.

The previous version `v6.0.13` doesn't have this problem.